# File.WriteAllTextAsync not writing exception e.message to log file c#

Tags: c#, logging

I'm making something to help me check my work and maybe some of my friends but it is not writing to the log files. Here is my code: `

```
catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (logs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error detected, saved to logs.");
                    if (!File.Exists(pathString))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pathString))
                        {
                            File.WriteAllTextAsync(fileName, e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.WriteAllTextAsync(fileName, e.Message);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Closing in 5 seconds.");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error detected, closing in 5 seconds.");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            }
```

`
Please help!

I tried File.AppendAllText, thinking it might work, but it had the same results. No text written to file. Everything works great except the logging. If you need the full code you can look [here](https://github.com/thatonehen/hwHelper/blob/main/Program.cs)

Comment: If you're using `WriteAllTextAsync`, you should be `await`ing it. Did you try `WriteAllText`? Did you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Your test for `File.Exists` here is worse than useless... you reach the same `WriteAllText` action on both paths, except that the "file doesn't exist" path *also* takes an exclusive lock on the file causing the write to fail.  `WriteAllText` will happily create a non-existent file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just had to remove async from the functions, I had copy and pasted it from another website. I don't know why the debugger wasn't telling me my functions were not async.

Comment: Removing the `async` keyword won't fix the litany of problems in your posted code - if it _looks_ like it works, then I can assure you it's entirely coincidental - unless you mean you _also_ converted all the calls to `WriteAllTextAsync` to `WriteAllText`.

Comment: The function wasn't await.